# Printf format string maximum width value (padding) %(??)d%n

Tags: c, printf

What is the maximum width value I can put in the `%d` format specifier? For example:

```
int c=0;   
printf("%1234567899d%n",0,&c);
printf("%d",c);
```

When I use large values the written value of `c` is `0`. Why is that?

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever change `c`.

Comment: @user4581301 `printf` changes it.

Comment: @eerorika neat. When did it start doing that?

Comment: I don't know if it's specified anywhere, but I'd be leery of putting anything larger than what an `int` can hold. Is this a theoretical question or do you really need multi-gigabyte strings?

Comment: @user4581301 Looks like it is in C89. I don't have documentation for pre-standard C.

Comment: @eerorika  Reading up on exactly what the `%n` specifier does. It's not in the '78  edition of K&R, so probably 89. I think I unpacked the wrong box. 78's not all that applicable today, is it?

Comment: Somewhere in a corner of my brain something like "minimum of 509 characters in total per printf must be supported by any implementation" is desperatley trying to find a (maybe ancient) source....

Comment: The C standard does not specify a limit; nothing is given for a limit in the `fprintf` specification (which also specifies `printf`) in C 2018 7.21.6.1. Apple Clang 11.0.0 on macOS 10.14.6 prints a lot of spaces followed by “01234567899”, so it appears to be processing the conversion specification faithfully. Your C implementation apparently gives up earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not stated explicitly, the type of the field width is most likely an `int`.  This is because if the field width is given as `*` then an `int` argument is expected.

Section 7.21.6.1p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `fprintf` function (any by extension `printf`) states the following regarding field witdh:

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated
> by an asterisk.  In this  case,  an `int` argument  supplies  the
> field  width  or  precision.   The  arguments specifying  field
> width,  or  precision,  or  both,  shall  appear  (in  that  order)
> before  the argument  (if  any)  to  be  converted.   A negative
> field  width  argument  is  taken  as  a `-` flag followed  by  a
> positive  field  width.   A  neg  ative  precision  argument  is
> taken  as  if  the precision were omitted.

I tested this on CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 18, and the largest width I could specify was 2147483614 which is 33 less than the max value for a signed 32 bit `int`.  If I use anything larger the first `printf` prints nothing and `c` remains 0.

Go generally speaking, the largest value you can expect for `c` would be `INT_MAX`, however the exact value will vary based on the implementation.

Comment: why in  other machines i found that max value can be written  is much less than `INT_MAX` not just a small value like cant exceed 9 digits  ?

Comment: @ShadyShahin That's entirely up to how that implementation wrote `printf`.

Comment: so why `c`  takes  its default value and not changes it to  maximum value in the implementation ? is that also depends on implementation?

Comment: In a particular implementation in glibc this check https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c.html#1501 will fail 33 less then INT_MAX

Answer (score 2):

> What is the maximum width value I can put in the %d format specifier?

The limit may be as small as 4095.

---

Aside from issues with specifying a *width* outside the positive `int` range, long output can incur *environmental limits*.

---

> Environmental limits  (fprintf)
> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095.  C17dr § 7.21.6.1 15

As I see this, an attempt to `"%(some large value)d"` print more than 4K (or some greater implementation limit) characters is UB.

---

Also for output to a *text file*:

> Environmental limits
> An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character. The value of the macro BUFSIZ shall be at least `256`.  C17dr § 7.21.2 9

Although `stdout` with `printf()` is not a *file*,  with re-directed output and `freopen()`, `printf()` may be subject to the above constraint.

Then printing an `int` with many digits can form a line exceeding 254 and some weak file system may not handle long lines.

Such a small 254 limit for a line length I have never seen, so I only include it as a reference, yet do not see it as a modern true limitation.

Comment: I find it odd that this is not the accepted answer.

Comment: @ryyker, earliest answers tend to get accepted.